# How can I create a borderless textbox in Google Chrome using CSS?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

How can I create a borderless HTML textbox to work in Google Chrome browser? I would prefer to do this in CSS, if possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

CSS 3 might help here:

```
input[type=text],
input[type=text]:hover,
input[type=text]:focus,
input[type=text]:active
{
    border: 0;
    outline: none;
    outline-offset: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the following to remove the border and the focus outline out of the text boxes.

```
input[type=text], textarea {
  border: 0;
}

input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

Comment: @Kriem: Replace `input[type=text]` with `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

in css, write

```
input, textarea, input:focus, textarea:focus {
     background:transparent;
     border:0;
}
```

it is important to make sure no border appears on focus

Answer (score -1):

A textarea? Like:

HTML: `<textarea></textarea>`

CSS: `textarea { border: none 0; }`

Comment: @Andrew: 'borderless' != 'outline-less', heh.

Comment: The question was geared towards Chrome specifically. I was pretty clear to me that the person HAD TRIED `border: 0` and was trying to get rid of the focus outline.